# trying to redirect with PHP Header("Location: ") function

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, header, location

I'm stumbling out of the blocks on this one.  I can't get this code to redirect the user to their product page immediately after submitting to create the product.  I've got three files create_product.php | product.php | & an external function page i'm calling a function from.  What i can't seem to get to work is the: header("location: product.php?product_id='.$product_id.'"); functionality.  All the stuff is input into the database correctly but when the user clicks submit to create the product i get the "That product does not exist" error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated (I know there are issues w/ security, etc...not worried about those at the moment, but rather just getting the "create product submit button to redirect the user to that newly created product page...and sorry for the low response rate (already been brought to my attention as a new user...i will start accepting all answers).  Thanks a ton for any help you can provide,

CREATE_PRODUCT.PHP PAGE:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['product_name'], $_POST['product_description'], $_FILES['fileField'])) {
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_description = $_POST['product_description'];
$image_name = $_FILES['fileField']['name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['fileField']['size'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'];

$allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
$image_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image_name)));

$errors = array();

if (empty($product_name) || empty($product_description) || empty($image_name)) {
    $errors[] = "All Fields are required";
} else {
    if (strlen($product_name) > 55 || strlen($product_description) > 255) {
        $errors[] = "One or more fields contains too many characters";
    } else {
        if (in_array($image_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'File type not allowed';
        }
        if ($image_size > 2097152) {
            $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2MB';
        }

    }

}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error, '<br/>';
        }
    } else {
        create_product($product_name, $product_description, $image_temp, $image_ext);

        header("location: product.php?product_id='.$product_id.'");
        exit();
    }
}
 ?>
```

PRODUCT.PHP PAGE:

```
<?php
// check to see the url variable product_id is set
if (isset($_GET['product_id'])) {
    $product_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['product_id']);
    // use this variable to check to see if this product ID exists...
    // if yes then get details...
    // if no then exit this script and give error

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$product_id' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $member_id = $row['member_id'];
            $timestamp = strftime("%b %d %Y", strtotime($row['timestamp']));
            $prodtitle = $row['bmtitle'];
            $proddesc = $row['bmdesc'];
        }

    } else {
        echo "That product does not exist";
        exit();
    }

} else {
    echo "Need data - product id needed to render this page is missing.";
    exit();
}

?>
```

I then go on within this product.php page to echo out the variables like $prodtitle, etc

LASTLY THE INCLUDED PRODUCT FUNCTIONS PAGE: (showing just create_product function):

```
<?php

function create_product($product_name, $product_description, $image_temp, $image_ext) {
$product_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($product_name));
$product_description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($product_description));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_id, member_id, timestamp, prodtitle, proddesc, image_temp, image_ext) VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['member_id']."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$product_name', '$product_description', '$image_temp', '$image_ext')");

mkdir('uploads/'.mysql_insert_id(), 0777);
mkdir('uploads/thumbs/'.mysql_insert_id(), 0777);

// place image & thumbnail in the respective folder
$bmid = mysql_insert_id();
$image_file = "$bmid."."jpg";
$location = "uploads/$bmid/$image_file";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],$location);

create_thumb('uploads/'.$bmid.'/', $image_file, 'uploads/thumbs/'.$bmid.'/');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
header("location: product.php?product_id='.$product_id.'");
```

should look like this:

```
header("Location: product.php?product_id=$product_id");
```

Please, note the absence of the single quotes.

Besides, it seems you have not defined the `$product_id` var at all in CREATE_PRODUCT.PHP

Comment: thanks aurelio, just changing the line & removing the quotes doesn't fix the problem, so as you said it must be not defining the variable.  where would the best place to do this be?

Comment: @BennyB Well, I think you should pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you defining `$product_id` anywhere. By any chance is the URL of the error page `product.php?product_id=` with nothing after the `=`?

Comment: it is Kolink...its actuall product.php?product_id='..' probably because as Aurelio mentioned above i wrote it incorrectly...

Comment: Hey Kolink, where would the best place to define the variable be? as in which file & within which block of code.  (i've tried a couple times & haven't gotten it to work...probably something small i'm missing).

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path for the location uri. You'll also need to ensure that no other output is sent to the client before the header is sent.

The relevant snip from http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```